# XSLT - Delete node based on a child element's attribute?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to delete a node based on a combination of particular child element attribute values.  In the example input below, I want to delete the entire 'cfb-score' node if the `vis-rank rank` and `home-rank rank` are both '0'.  I have tried many expressions, but can't seem to come up with a solution.  Some times I can get it to delete absolutely all of the `<cfb-scores>`.  Sometimes it does nothing.

```
    <cfb-score>
    <gamecode code="201509030004" global-id="1526672"/>
    <source id="1"/>
    <gametype id="1" type="Regular Season" detail="" round="" round-name=""/>
    <gamestate status-id="4" status="Final" quarter="4" minutes="" seconds="" team-possession-id="" yards-from-goal="" down="" distance="" segment-number="4" active-state="false"/>
    <outcome-visit outcome-id="2" outcome="Loss" conf-outcome-id="0" conference-outcome="No game"/>
    <outcome-home outcome-id="1" outcome="Win" conf-outcome-id="0" conference-outcome="No game"/>
    <vis-name name="Braves" alias="Alc"/>
    <vis-conf conference="Southwestern Athletic" abbrev="SWAC" id="23"/>
    <vis-rank rank="0" playoff-rank=""/>
    <vis-score score="6" timeouts-left="0"/>
    <home-name name="Yellow Jackets" alias="GaTech"/>
    <home-conf conference="Atlantic Coast" abbrev="ACC" id="1"/>
    <home-rank rank="16" playoff-rank=""/>
    <home-score score="69" timeouts-left="2"/>
    </cfb-score>
    <cfb-score>
    <gamecode code="201509030202" global-id="1528079"/>
    <source id="1"/>
    <gametype id="1" type="Regular Season" detail="" round="" round-name=""/>
    <gamestate status-id="4" status="Final" quarter="4" minutes="" seconds="" team-possession-id="" yards-from-goal="" down="" distance="" segment-number="4" active-state="false"/>
    <outcome-visit outcome-id="2" outcome="Loss" conf-outcome-id="0" conference-outcome="No game"/>
    <outcome-home outcome-id="1" outcome="Win" conf-outcome-id="0" conference-outcome="No game"/>
    <vis-name name="Wildcats" alias="Vill"/>
    <vis-conf conference="Colonial Athletic Association" abbrev="CAA" id="98"/>
    <vis-rank rank="0" playoff-rank=""/>
    <vis-score score="15" timeouts-left="0"/>
    <home-name name="Huskies" alias="UConn"/>
    <home-conf conference="American Athletic Conference" abbrev="AAC" id="122"/>
    <home-rank rank="0" playoff-rank=""/>
    <home-score score="20" timeouts-left="2"/>
    </cfb-score>
```

I guess I should point out that the XML above is the OUTPUT of what my style-sheet is already doing, which involves a lot of pruning, some renaming, and a little restructuring.  My full XSLT + a sample of the original input is below.

statxform.xslt:

```
<!--STATS.COM >> PADS XML TRANSFORMER -BY JAKE BALLARD 2015-->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<!--Copy all nodes into the workspace-->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<!--Delete stuff we don't care about-->
<xsl:template match="team-city|team-code|quarter|record|date|time|local-game-date|local-time|week|coverage|bowl|stadium"/>
<!--We need to rename stuff in the visiting-team 
and home-team nodes with a unique prefix so they 
are still distinguishible after flattening-->
<!--Rename Visitor Children-->
<xsl:template match="visiting-team/team-name">
    <vis-name>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|visiting-team/team-name"/>
    </vis-name>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="visiting-team/team-conference">
    <vis-conf>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|visiting-team/team-conference"/>
    </vis-conf>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="visiting-team/team-rank">
    <vis-rank>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|visiting-team/team-rank"/>
    </vis-rank>
</xsl:template>    
<xsl:template match="visiting-team/linescore">
    <vis-score>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|visiting-team/linescore"/>
    </vis-score>
</xsl:template>
<!--Rename Home Children-->
<xsl:template match="home-team/team-name">
    <home-name>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|home-team/team-name"/>
    </home-name>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="home-team/team-conference">
    <home-conf>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|home-team/team-conference"/>
    </home-conf>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="home-team/team-rank">
    <home-rank>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|home-team/team-rank"/>
    </home-rank>
</xsl:template>    
<xsl:template match="home-team/linescore">
    <home-score>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|home-team/linescore"/>
    </home-score>
</xsl:template>
<!--Delete Parent Nodes for Visiting Team and Home Team, 
but keep contents under <cfb-score> so PADS has a unified table to peruse-->    
<xsl:template match="visiting-team" >
<xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="home-team" >
<xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="cfb-score/*[@rank = '0' ]"/>
<!--ROLL TIDE-->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the last template, you can see my latest attempt at filtering the non-ranked games. It appears to do nothing.

input.xml sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sports-statistics>
<sports-scores>
<date year="2015" month="9" date="5" day="6"/>
<time hour="23" minute="32" second="09" timezone="Eastern" utc-hour="-4" utc-minute="00"/>
<version number="6"/>
<league global-id="16" name="College Football" alias="CFB" display-name=""/>
<season season="2015"/>
    <cfb-scores>
 <cfb-score>
   <date year="2015" month="9" date="3" day="4"/>
   <time hour="18" minute="00" timezone="Eastern" utc-hour="-4" utc-minute="00"/>
   <local-game-date year="2015" month="9" date="3" day="4"/>
   <local-time hour="18" minute="00"/>
   <week week="2"/>
   <gamecode code="201509030070" global-id="1526673"/>
   <coverage level="30"/>
   <source id="2"/>
   <gametype id="1" type="Regular Season" detail="" round="" round-name=""/>
   <stadium name="Bank of America Stadium" city="Charlotte" state="North Carolina" state-id="33" country-name="United States" country-id="1" id="1022" global-id="3098"/>
   <bowl id="0" name="" full-name=""/>
   <gamestate status-id="4" status="Final" quarter="4" minutes="" seconds="" team-possession-id="" yards-from-goal="" down="" distance="" segment-number="4" active-state="false"/>
   <outcome-visit outcome-id="2" outcome="Loss" conf-outcome-id="0" conference-outcome="No game"/>
   <outcome-home outcome-id="1" outcome="Win" conf-outcome-id="0" conference-outcome="No game"/>
   <visiting-team>
     <team-name name="Tar Heels" alias="UNC"/>
     <team-city city="North Carolina"/>
     <team-code id="6" global-id="3412" division="1"/>
     <team-conference conference="Atlantic Coast" abbrev="ACC" id="1"/>
     <team-rank rank="0" playoff-rank=""/>
     <record wins="0" losses="1" ties="0" pct=".000"/>
     <linescore score="13" timeouts-left="0">
        <quarter quarter="1" score="7"/>
        <quarter quarter="2" score="6"/>
        <quarter quarter="3" score="0"/>
        <quarter quarter="4" score="0"/>
     </linescore>
   </visiting-team>
   <home-team>
     <team-name name="Gamecocks" alias="SC"/>
     <team-city city="South Carolina"/>
     <team-code id="70" global-id="3475" division="1"/>
     <team-conference conference="Southeastern" abbrev="SEC" id="8"/>
     <team-rank rank="0" playoff-rank=""/>
     <record wins="1" losses="0" ties="0" pct="1.000"/>
     <linescore score="17" timeouts-left="2">
        <quarter quarter="1" score="0"/>
        <quarter quarter="2" score="10"/>
        <quarter quarter="3" score="0"/>
        <quarter quarter="4" score="7"/>
     </linescore>
   </home-team>
 </cfb-score>
 <cfb-score>
   <date year="2015" month="9" date="3" day="4"/>
   <time hour="18" minute="00" timezone="Eastern" utc-hour="-4" utc-minute="00"/>
   <local-game-date year="2015" month="9" date="3" day="4"/>
   <local-time hour="18" minute="00"/>
   <week week="2"/>
   <gamecode code="201509030210" global-id="1530288"/>
   <coverage level="30"/>
   <source id="1"/>
   <gametype id="1" type="Regular Season" detail="" round="" round-name=""/>
   <stadium name="Bright House Networks Stadium" city="Orlando" state="Florida" state-id="9" country-name="United States" country-id="1" id="2213" global-id="5790"/>
   <bowl id="0" name="" full-name=""/>
   <gamestate status-id="4" status="Final" quarter="4" minutes="" seconds="" team-possession-id="" yards-from-goal="" down="" distance="" segment-number="4" active-state="false"/>
   <outcome-visit outcome-id="1" outcome="Win" conf-outcome-id="0" conference-outcome="No game"/>
   <outcome-home outcome-id="2" outcome="Loss" conf-outcome-id="0" conference-outcome="No game"/>
   <visiting-team>
     <team-name name="Golden Panthers" alias="FIU"/>
     <team-city city="FIU"/>
     <team-code id="2307" global-id="5090" division="1"/>
     <team-conference conference="Conference USA" abbrev="CUSA" id="72"/>
     <team-rank rank="0" playoff-rank=""/>
     <record wins="1" losses="0" ties="0" pct="1.000"/>
     <linescore score="15" timeouts-left="1">
        <quarter quarter="1" score="3"/>
        <quarter quarter="2" score="0"/>
        <quarter quarter="3" score="6"/>
        <quarter quarter="4" score="6"/>
     </linescore>
   </visiting-team>
   <home-team>
     <team-name name="Knights" alias="UCF"/>
     <team-city city="UCF"/>
     <team-code id="210" global-id="3615" division="1"/>
     <team-conference conference="American Athletic Conference" abbrev="AAC" id="122"/>
     <team-rank rank="0" playoff-rank=""/>
     <record wins="0" losses="1" ties="0" pct=".000"/>
     <linescore score="14" timeouts-left="0">
        <quarter quarter="1" score="7"/>
        <quarter quarter="2" score="7"/>
        <quarter quarter="3" score="0"/>
        <quarter quarter="4" score="0"/>
     </linescore>
   </home-team>
 </cfb-score>
 </cfb-scores>
 </sports-scores>
 </sports-statistics>
```

Comment: Your newly added XML has no `vis-rank` or `home-rank`, only `team-rank`. Or rather `team-rank`s.

Comment: As I said, the XSLT which is posted in the original transforms the input and vis-rank and home-ranks are renamed results of it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I made this clear, everything that you see in my xslt works as expected except for the last template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***(Edited)***

> I want to delete the entire 'cfb-score' node if the 'vis-rank rank'
>   and 'home-rank rank' are both '0'.

[groan] Why don't you formulate the requirement with respect to the *input*? That is:

> Delete the `cfb-score` node if `@rank` is 0 in both
>   `visiting-team/team-rank` and `home-team/team-rank`.

Which is easy to achieve using:

```
<xsl:template match="cfb-score[visiting-team/team-rank/@rank=0 and home-team/team-rank/@rank=0]"/>
```

---

BTW, your stylesheet has this comment next to the identity transform template:

```
<!--Copy all nodes into the workspace-->
```

That is a misconception. There is no "workspace" here. The template establishes a default rule, which other templates with higher priority may override. Eventually each node is processed only once, by the template that matches it best.

I am mentioning this because I believe it's the same misconception that caused the initial confusion here: the stylesheet reads **only** the input.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  However, I just tried it and my output is still the same.

Comment: @JakeBallard Show us your attempt so that we can fix it, instead of having to write it out for you from scratch. And while you're at it, make your input **complete** - see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: A minimized, but complete example is what I would like to see. That means removing all parts that are not relevant to the problem, but still retaining valid code - unlike your XML, that lacks a root element. -- See a working example here: http://xsltransform.net/jyH9rNu

Comment: Just to be safe, I made a new style sheet that works on the output of my main one. I cannot post code in this comment as you well know, but suffice it to say that it starts by copying all nodes, then the template suggested above.  It runs without error, but when I diff the output and input there was no change.  I am quite perplexed at this point.

Comment: @JakeBallard  "*I made a new style sheet that works on the output of my main one.*" That would work if you had used my original suggestion. Now that you have clarified your requirement, all you need to do is add the above template to your existing stylesheet.

Comment: Thank you again for the help.  I'm sure I have a lot of misconceptions, considering yesterday I didn't even know what XSLT was.  I am far from being a true software developer, just a sys-admin faced with a problem.  I am always grateful for the help I get on stackoverflow.com.  Most of the time I am able to get 99% of the way through my scripting challenges without even having to ask a new question.  Some of the fixes I have come up with here are impossible to put price tags on.